# Installing SQL Server 2008 on a development machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, installation

I am setting up a new Windows 7 machine.

I have installed VS 2008 Team System Developer / Database Ed. I have also installed SP1 and ran windows update.

When I now try to install SQL Server on the machine it fails because I have a "Previous version" of visual studio.

Anyone know why I am getting this error or how to fix it?

**EDIT**

I found this link on the problem http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139

But it does not really cover the whole problem, on my PC it failed even though I had SP1. I suspect that it was the Team Explorer that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be you are trying to install the Business Intelligence Development Studio, which installs a version of Visual Studio 2008, when you are installing SQL Server.

I would try to install just the database components first then if you need other components do them on a secondary install, the other obvious option is is to uninstall Visual Studio 2008, then install Sql Server then re-install Visual Studio 2008 Team again.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up uninstalling VS. I could install the database, but not the management console.